# Running wx python's event loop from another framework

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, pyglet

I'm writing a game using Pyglet, but I'd like to include a few wx dialogs.
I can do simple things, like text entry dialogs and message boxes (as modal dialogs that block until ok or cancel is pressed), but in a multi-player environment... That fails hard.
I'm using wx python, Phoenix 4.0.0b1, and I need to "drive" wx's event loop from pyglet. I can schedule functions to run at any interval, but I'm  not sure how exactly to do the "driving" of the event loop.
There is [EventLoopBase](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.EventLoopBase.html), and that mentions methods like 'Dispatch', 'DispatchTimeout', and 'Pending', but I'm not sure if wx.App.MainLoop() does anything special before running wx.EventLoopBase.Run(); I don't think I can just create a wx.App() instance and have a function check if there are events pending and (if so), run Dispatch.

Does anyone know the "right" way to do this? I'd rather not shove the loop off to another thread if I don't have to.

This might end up being not much of a question if what I outlined above does in deed work, but just in case I'm throwing this out there to make sure I won't be breaking things if it appears to work, or if it doesn't work at all.

Update: below is some code I wrote to try to solve this. Instead of getting an instance of wx.App, I get one of this class and call MainLoop() as normal.
It doesn't work the way it needs too; wx doesn't consider the event loop I'm using to be the "main" one, and I believe this is what causes problems with dialogs I run Show() on.

Hopefully this will illustrate better what I'm trying to do, which is call a single method at an interval to process wx's loop.
Normally, MainLoop() on a wx.App instance blocks while doing this, effectively making it so wx needs to drive the loop(s) of anything else, while I'm trying to get this to work the other way around.
There's also a thread on wx's mailing list [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/miqsS1EO4K8) that presents my same problem, though no other solution than "just let wx be the main loop and run pyglet's loop on a wx.Timer" has been suggested. As I mentioned there, however, pyglet's loop will be doing most of the work, so it seems to make more sense to try to do it this way.

The code:

```
# Overridden classes for wx

import wx

class App(wx.App):

    def MainLoop(self, clock, loop_interval, idle_ticks=50):
        """Indicates that the event loop should start.
This implementation uses pyglet's clock to drive the event loop, and will return immediately after scheduling the driving of the loop.
Args:
    clock: pyglet's clock instance; is used to schedule the main loop.
    loop_interval: in milliseconds, how often the wx loop should be ticked (events processed).
    idle_ticks: how many ticks with no UI events to process should elapse before ProcessIdle is called.
        """
        self.loop_interval = loop_interval
        self.idle_ticks = idle_ticks
            self.ticks = 0
        self.evtloop = wx.GUIEventLoop()
        wx.EventLoop.SetActive(self.evtloop)
        self.run = True
        clock.schedule_interval(self.drive_loop, loop_interval)

    def drive_loop(self, *a):
        """Drives the main wx event loop."""
        if self.run == True:
            while self.evtloop.Pending(): # if there is at least one event to be processed
                self.evtloop.Dispatch() # process one event
            else: # no UI events
                self.ticks += 1
                if self.ticks >= self.idle_ticks:
                    self.evtloop.ProcessIdle()
                    self.ticks = 0
```

Comment: Could you perhaps give us a piece of the relevant code? Something we can work with? For instance, how do you set up the base event loop?

Comment: Okay, I updated the question with a bit more info and some code I've tried.